# XTEST definitions for mouse buttons - remote control app

Tags: c++, xserver

I'm currently working on a fork of local networked remote control app for an embedded device with touchscreen (the DSI2KEY homebrew for the Nintendo DSI, a fork of https://github.com/sypherce/ds2key). I've recently started working on fixing up the linux side of things, and it uses C++ and XTEST for the computer/server side (in this case, the DSI is considered a client).

My question is the following:
XTEST has some nice definitions of various keyboard buttons in the included `#include <X11/keysym.h>`, however I'm struggling to find any definitions of mouse buttons. Do such buttons exist, and if not, how do I determine which codes to pass to `XTestFakeButtonEvent`?

Comment: It seems likely that they're the `XK_Pointer_...` definitions in `keysym.h`, but I haven't verified it.